# Matplotlib with dual scale mouse over

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot some curves with matplotlib using the default gui component and have some trouble to select which of the two y-axes that the mouse over functionality should select. The default case seems to be that ax2 gets selected but I would like to use ax1 instead. Is this possible to fix in some easy way?

This is the code I use at the moment to plot my curves.

Best regards Anders Olme

```
delta=np.median(np.diff(measurementvalues.measvalues))  
myscale=10
myrange=(measurementvalues.lowerlimit - delta*myscale, measurementvalues.upperlimit + delta*myscale)

figure = plt.figure()
ax1 = figure.add_subplot(111)
(n, bins, patches) = ax1.hist(measurementvalues.measvalues, 10, range=myrange, normed=0, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
mean = np.average(measurementvalues.measvalues)
sigma = np.std(measurementvalues.measvalues)
y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mean, sigma)

ax2.plot(bins, y, 'r-', linewidth=1)
ax1.set_xlabel('Measvlues')
ax2.set_ylabel('Probability')
ax1.set_title(r'$\mathrm{Histogram\ of\ measvalues:}\ \mu=$'+str(mean)+r'$,\ \sigma=$'+str(sigma)+r'$$')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Are you trying to use FigureCanvas.mpl_connect() to interact with the figure? The posted code only shows how the figure is generated; can you post the code that describes how you are trying to interact with the figure?

Comment: He's talking about the coordinate labels in the bottom right hand side of interactive plots.  No callbacks involved, just the default plot.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following after calling twinx

```
ax3 = ax1.figure.add_axes(ax1.get_position(True), sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1,
        frameon=False)
ax3.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax3.yaxis.set_visible(False)
```

You will also need to change plt.grid(True) to ax1.grid(True)

Comment: this should be accepted as answer, it works. Why the need to change grid?

Comment: @dashesy I recommend changing from `plt.grid` to `ax1.grid` so that it explicitly sets the grid for `ax1`.  Perhaps the OP actually wants the grid on `ax2`, in which case there is no need to change that.